# Flexbox change width of element on wrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

From this crude diagram where the black outline is the flexbox element and the blue/red are two nested elements inside the flexbox:

[image]

How would I go about achieving this result using flexbox?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

Sooo, here we go, let's start with the markup

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Now you need to set the properties for your container, we are doing it mobile first so I added a `flex-direction: column;`

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

Then the height for the divs

```
.div1{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.div2{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

And for the last, you need to make a media query for desktop

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
      flex-direction: row;
  }

  .div2{
    width: 20%;
    max-width: 500px;
  }

  .div1{
    width: 80%;
  }
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/wQzNOo) you have a codepen! Let me know if that help!

Comment: unfortunately this requires the viewport width, the flexbox may be contained in a smaller div..